# Reusable image with dynamic text inside

Tags: java, android, imageview, horizontalscrollview

Hello I have a HorizontalScrollView that I would like to populate with some images of a fixed size with dynamic text inside that image. Here is an example of one of these images:

```
******    //where "AK" is a player's initials 
* AK *    // and 34 is his score
* 34 *    // and each image will have a unique color
******
```

I want to populate my HorizontalScrollView with a variable number of these and be able to dynamically update their initials and score every so often. Right now, I am only able to populate the HorizontalScrollView with a predefined number of TextViews in my xml file. How do I create a template layout for these images and dynamically update the values inside them? Ideally, this image will just be a circle with the initials and score centered inside of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have similar task. I suggest use the follow: 1. Create nine-patch image and define content area where you would like to put your text. Also define stretchable patches for this drawable. 2. For TextView define this drawables as background and provide it some padding. I hope it would help. If content is changed image should stretched based on content.

Answer (score 0):

you can set image as background of Relative Layout and set Text in the center of this Relative Layout in your template layout.

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        adapter.addItem(new ModelPlayer("AK", "37"));
        adapter.addItem(new ModelPlayer("BK", "36"));
        adapter.addItem(new ModelPlayer("CK", "35"));
        adapter.addItem(new ModelPlayer("DK", "34"));
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGetList" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelPlayer> players;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        players = new ArrayList<ModelPlayer>();
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelPlayer> players) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public void addItem(ModelPlayer player) {
        players.add(player);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return players.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtPlayer, txtScore;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtPlayer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayer);
            holder.txtScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ModelPlayer player = players.get(position);
        holder.txtPlayer.setText(player.getPlayer());
        holder.txtScore.setText(player.getScore());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

layout_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPlayer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="AK" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPlayer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="34" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ModelPlayer

```
 public class ModelPlayer {
    private String player, score;

    public ModelPlayer(String player, String score) {
        super();
        this.player = player;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(String player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

drawable/shape_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#fa0000" >
    </solid>

</shape>
```

I hope this example will helpful to you

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, that was quick! However, I believe this implementation orders the circles in a vertical fashion. I was looking to have these images on the top of the screen ordered horizontally.

Comment: @vagabond_cell For horizontal you can use Horizontal ListView Link : https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView